# How do I disable property auto-synthesis of properties in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, llvm

I have written a library to automatically generate NSUserDefaults accessors based on `@dynamic` properties that you declare in a 'preferences' class (see [PAPreferences](https://github.com/dhennessy/PAPreferences)). You write the property in a .m file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasSeenIntro;
```

and then add this to the .h file:

```
@dynamic hasSeenIntro;
```

This works fine but if the user accidentally forgets to put in the `@dynamic` line, then the compiler will automatically generate an equivalent `@synthesize` line instead. There will be no warnings but of course my code won't be invoked for that property.

I'd like to know if there's a way to disable automatic property synthesis just for this class.

**Update:**

Thanks to Nikolai's answer, I remembered that it's possible to promote LLVM warnings to errors and wrapping the declaration with that error achieves the effect I was looking for (an error will be raised if the user forgets to specify the `@dynamic` line):

```
// Ensure we get an error if we forget to add @dynamic for each property
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wobjc-missing-property-synthesis"

@interface Preferences : PAPreferences

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasSeenIntro;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger pressCount;

@end

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to do this via code.

There's a compiler warning (controlled via Xcode's build setting "Implicit Synthesized Properties", `CLANG_WARN_OBJC_MISSING_PROPERTY_SYNTHESIS`) but you have to manually set this on the implementation file, so for your case that's not really helpful.

Here's another idea: Change your implementation to add the properties using a category on `PAPreferences` instead of a subclass. Then the compiler can't synthesize the accessors and will emit a warning if the `@dynamic` is missing.

```
@interface PAPreferences (SynthesizedProperties)
@property int foo;
@end

@implementation PAPreferences (SynthesizedProperties)
@end
```

Result:

```
> warning: property 'foo' requires method 'foo' to be defined - use @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this category
```

Additionally (or instead) you can introspect the property during runtime to detect accidentally synthesized accessors and emit a warning in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the options - I didn't want to go the category route because the user code would be a bit harder to understand. However, I had forgotten about the property synthesis compiler warning. The result I ended up with was promoting that warning to an error just for the preferences class.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do that, as in previous Xcode versions there was no way to flag wether you had forgotten to @synthesize a specific property. Only at runtime you'd have a Unrecognize selector error being raised.